# Use a variable set to ng-click to change template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a list of links and I want each of them to change the DOM on the current page
using ng-click and templating, how would I do that?

Edit: I guess what I am trying to understand is how to move as much of the logic away from the .html file and into my app.js  file. I'm a little new to JS and Angular and don't know where or how to pass "active" to choose what I'd like to place inside 
For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" ng-click="active='foo1'"><h1>foo1</h1></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" ng-click="active='foo2'"><h1>foo2</h1></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" ng-click="active='foo3'"><h1>foo3</h1></a>
  </li>
</ul>  

<active></active>
```

Where the active element displays only what template is set to the active one. 
ie;  the template associated with foo1 is displayed, and then if foo2 is clicked the template for foo2 replaces foo1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the implementation of `<active>`, but you can use `ng-include` to implement what you are expecting

`<active ng-include='active'></active>`

Now create a client side or server side template with the name which matches variable `active`  defined on scope and corresponding template would get loaded

A template definition could be like

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="foo1">
    <!-- html template for foo here-->
</script>
```

See [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I was looking for. I had used <active> just to be descriptive but maybe it wasn't helpful. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-show/ng-hide. Basically something like this.

```
<div ng-show="foo1">
  <p> This will only show when foo1 is true on your scope.
</div>

<div ng-show="foo2">
  <p> This will only show when foo2 is true on your scope.
</div>

<div ng-show="foo3">
  <p> This will only show when foo3 is true on your scope.
</div>
```

Also if you're wanting to keep the logic of the active = 'foo1' just change up the logic in the ng-show. Usually you want to keep logic out of the view though, so move that to your controller.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to understand was how to move as much as possible to the controller. I'm a little new to js and angular and don't really know how or where to pass active.